# creating a "dig out" game with a one dimensional array instead of two?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a project in which I have to create a "dig out" game (A game in which you need to find coins,ect.There are so many games like this,like Dig Out and Mars Miner,ect.I want to create a simple version of them containing monsters.For more information you can look it up on Google.)without the multidimensional arrays.I have to create it with only a one-dimensional array.I draw the board and everything,but I have a problem and that is I don't want the player or the monsters to accidentally jump on a wrong place.

For example,[in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iESSw.png)The player can go to the upper line's right if they intend to go to left.

It's not that much of a problem for the player,but since I want the monster's movements to be automatic,I want to learn to control it.
These are the variables:

```html
 static String name;
 static int row,column;
 static int coins;
 static char[] gamePlace;
 static int i; //The most used variable for the loops.
 static int a=0;//Will be increased by one every time a new soil or stone is added.
 static int playerIndex;//The index of the player.
 static int go=0; //The index player wants to go to.
 static int dig=0; //The index player wants to dig out.
 static int monsterPlace;  //The index of the monster.
```

This is my board method:

```html
 public static void printBoard() {  //Prints the board.
  int j,k=0;
  
  for(i=0;i<column+2;i++)          //For the beauty of the game, a frame is drawn.
   System.out.print("-");
  System.out.println("");
  
  for(i=0;i<row;i++) {
   
   System.out.print("|");
   for(j=0;j<column;j++) {
    System.out.print(gamePlace[k]);
    k++;
    
  }
   System.out.println("|");
  }
  
  for(i=0;i<column+2;i++)
   System.out.print("-");
  
 }
```

So these were my monster methods:

```
    (I kept getting index out of bounds exception so I surrounded the "monster" method with try and catch,but now the monster doesn't move.What do you think I should do?)
```

```html
 public static void monster() {
  
  int monsterTurn = (int)(Math.random()*(4+1)-1); //Getting a number in between 1 and 4.
  try {
  if(monsterTurn==1 && gamePlace[monsterPlace+1]=='.' || gamePlace[monsterPlace+1]=='!' ) {
   monsterMove(monsterPlace, monsterPlace+1); //If 1 is randomly chosen and the right is unoccupied the monster will go there.
            monsterPlace=monsterPlace+1;
  }
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
  }
  
  try {
  
  if(monsterTurn==2 && gamePlace[monsterPlace-1]=='.' || gamePlace[monsterPlace-1]=='!') {
   monsterMove(monsterPlace, monsterPlace-1); //If 2 is randomly chosen and the left is unoccupied the monster will go there.
   monsterPlace=monsterPlace-1;
  }
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
  }
  
  
  try {
  
   if(monsterTurn==3 && gamePlace[monsterTurn-column]=='.' || gamePlace[monsterPlace-column]=='!') {
   monsterMove(monsterPlace, monsterPlace-column);  //If 3 is randomly chosen and up is unoccupied the monster will go there.
   monsterPlace=monsterPlace-column;
  }
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
  }
  
  
  try {
  if(monsterTurn==4 && gamePlace[monsterTurn+column]=='.' || gamePlace[monsterPlace+column]=='!') {
   monsterMove(monsterPlace, monsterPlace+column); //If 3 is randomly chosen and down is unoccupied the monster will go there.
      monsterPlace = monsterPlace+column;
  }
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
   
  }

   
  
 }
 
 public static void monsterMove(int place,int placeToGo) {
  char temp;
  int monsterColumn=0;
  int goToPlace=0;
  int columnNum=column;  //Created to make the comparison between the monster's column and the place it's going to go easier.
  
  for(i=0;i<place;i++)  //Checks which column the monster is in and which column it is going to go,so it wouldn't accidently jump on the other side of the board.
   if(i==columnNum) {
    monsterColumn++;
    columnNum +=column;
    }
  
  for(i=0;i<placeToGo;i++)
   if(i==columnNum) {
    goToPlace++;
    columnNum +=column;
   }
  
  
  if(monsterColumn==goToPlace) { //If the columns were the same,the monster will move.Else,the movement method will be recalled.
  temp = gamePlace[place];
  gamePlace[place] = gamePlace[placeToGo];
  gamePlace[placeToGo]=temp;
  }
  
  else
   monster();
  
 }
```

Comment: Please provide more context as to the specific goal you are working towards right now and how you are currently attempting to address it. You haven't provided how "column" and "gamePlace" variables are created or used, a sense of expected input / output, or really even what is "correct movement", as we don't know what you mean by "accidentally jump on a wrong place"

Comment: Ok,I will now.Sorry for the late response.

Comment: I would put my entire code here,but a lot of other students are also coding this and my professor and the TAs might think I copied the code from the internet,so I just put some parts of it.Not only do we get no points when we copy something,but we also get a negative point as well,so just in case,I can't post all of it.

Comment: @ElenaAsi Then maybe you should try this by yourself, else you will be missing out on the learning process. Try to find a way to debug your code, to note down what is happening, and see if you can come up with an answer by yourself. The learning steps include having a hard time solving problems, then learning from your mistakes. If you skip those critical steps, your professional career will suffer from it. I sympathize with you, it can be hard at first, but the more you try the better you will become. There's no fast track to being a good programmer.

Comment: @Laf I have created one that randomly chooses a value,but I have a problem and that is, the monster just randomly chooses a place and the game will most probably get a index out of range exception in the smaller sized boards(The board is resizable). So I think I should add something to it?I don't know much about exceptions,so I don't know if adding anything would work.

Comment: @Laf Would adding a try and catch be a solution for that?I will edit my post,adding the monster methods.

Comment: I tried surrounding the "monster" method with try and catch,but the monster doesn't seem to move...What should I do?